# Headless chrome on centos server not working

Tags: google-chrome, laravel-5, centos7, laravel-dusk

I am using Centos 7 server to host php laravel 5.5 application. I have written laravel dusk browser tests. To run these tests on server I will need to run google chrome in headless mode. I have installed google chrome and chromium driver on my server. I have also tried with Xvfb. None of this working. It always gives error that shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented.
[Added error which I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3oAs.png)

Any suggestion to make laravel dusk automated test working on centos 7 with headless google chrome? We are using Jenkins for continuous integration.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue with headless chrome on centos.
The problem was with Default Fonts. We solved it with:

```
yum install ipa-gothic-fonts xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi xorg-x11-utils xorg-x11-fonts-cyrillic xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 xorg-x11-fonts-misc -y
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes it worked now. Not sure what fixed it, but yes we installed fonts as you mentioned as well used Xvfb with Jenkins.